# Corner Banner - Add to Page

Tags: html, css

So I have a parallax scrolling web page you can see it [here](http://grantsiders.com/Parallasx/) I would like to be able to have a link my blog which obviously is not on the same page because its not a regular style web page. I have gotten the ribbon/banner to show up on a page that is not like my web page, you can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PyXEL/). I'm simply using a div to  show it.

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="ribbonw"><div class="ribbon"><a href="google.com">Visit my blog </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

How would I add it to the web page with out screwing up the page. I have done some research on how to make the banner, but I'm not sure how to add it to the page because when ever I do it just either doesn't show up on the page or is just a long white  strip on the page.

So to summerize up what I'm asking is how do I add a banner like the one on the second link to my page I would like it to look something like the banner on [this](http://scriptsrc.net/) page.

Comment: 403 - I don't even have permission to view your page...

Comment: Your first link gives a 403 error. That said, have you tried absolute positioning it at right:0px, top:0px?

Comment: I'm guessing so, since that's what you did in the second link.

Comment: @Daniel Try the link now.

Comment: @AaronF I had to add the banner to the inside of the first slide div. I explain more in the answer below.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question for future users what I had to do was add the code above into the actual first "slide" or first div. What I mean by that is that in a parallax scrolling page you have your pages split up into divs. So i just had to add my banner into the first div. It looks something like this:

```
<!-- begin slide 1 -->
<div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
<div class="wrapperr">
       <div class="ribbonw">
                <div class="ribbon">
                    <a href="google.com">Visit my blog</a>
                 </div>
       </div>
</div>
more content here
</div> 
<!-- end slide 1 -->
```

as you can see I just had to add the content into the slide. I had it outside before therefore creating another slide.